# object.watch(), getting new value

Tags: javascript, this, javascript-objects, dom-events

In **Firefox**, I've got several objects that I need to trigger an event when a particular property of each is changed.  I'm using object.watch(), however when I return the value of the property that was changed using "this", it returns the old value the first time, and "undefined" the second and subsequent times:

```
var myObject = {
        "aProperty": 1
    };

function propChanged(prop) {
    alert(prop);
}

myObject.watch("aProperty", function () {
    propChanged(this.aProperty);
});

myObject.aProperty = 2;//alerts "1"
myObject.aProperty = 3;//alerts "undefined"
```

The reason I can't just say alert(myObject.aProperty) is because this is meant to be a dynamic code that will apply the event handler to several, possibly unknown objects.

I'm just unsure exactly how to dynamically get the new value of the property using the watch method.  I'm setting up a prototype for IE for this, so I'm not worried about it not working there. I just need to understand "this" and how it applies to the watch method's owner.

Edit>>

Here's the new code I'm using for cross browser, including the IE et al prototype:

```
var myObject = {};

if (!Object.prototype.watch) {
    Object.prototype.watch = function (prop, handler) {
        var oldval = this[prop], newval = oldval,
        getter = function () {
            return newval;
        },
        setter = function (val) {
            oldval = newval;
            return newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val);
        };
        if (delete this[prop]) { // can't watch constants
            if (Object.defineProperty) // ECMAScript 5
                Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
                    get: getter,
                    set: setter
                });
            else if (Object.prototype.__defineGetter__ && Object.prototype.__defineSetter__) { // legacy
                Object.prototype.__defineGetter__.call(this, prop, getter);
                Object.prototype.__defineSetter__.call(this, prop, setter);
            }
        }
    };
}

if (!Object.prototype.unwatch) {
    Object.prototype.unwatch = function (prop) {
        var val = this[prop];
        delete this[prop]; // remove accessors
        this[prop] = val;
    };
}


function propChanged(t, p, o, n) {
    alert(o);
}

Object.defineProperty(myObject, "aProperty", {value: 2,
    writable: true,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true});

myObject.watch("aProperty", propChanged);

myObject.aProperty = 3; //alerts 3
myObject.aProperty = 4;  //alerts 4 (n is undefined in propChanged?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the value you want the property to have from the function you pass to watch.

```
myObject.watch("aProperty", function (prop, oldval, newval) {
    propChanged(newVal);
    return newVal;
});
```

should do it.

See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) for a full detail of the function but the relevant bit is

> Watches for assignment to a property named prop in this object, calling `handler(prop, oldval, newval)` whenever `prop` is set **and storing the return value in that property**. A watchpoint can filter (or nullify) the value assignment, by returning a modified `newval` (or by returning `oldval`).

EDIT

Your edited code might work better this way

```
Object.prototype.watch = function (prop, handler) {
    var fromPrototype = !Object.hasOwnProperty.call(this, prop),
    val = this[prop],
    getter = function () {
        return fromPrototype ? Object.getPrototypeOf(this)[prop] : val;
    },
    setter = function (newval) {
        fromPrototype = false;
        return val = handler.call(this, prop, val, newval);
    };
    if (delete this[prop]) { // can't watch constants
        if (Object.defineProperty) { // ECMAScript 5
            Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
                get: getter,
                set: setter,
                configurable: true,
                enumerable: true
            });
        } else if (Object.prototype.__defineGetter__ && Object.prototype.__defineSetter__) { // legacy
            Object.prototype.__defineGetter__.call(this, prop, getter);
            Object.prototype.__defineSetter__.call(this, prop, setter);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't think I'm following you.  I thought that's what I was doing.

Comment: Ah.. thanks.  I was just digging through the method's getter and setter and saw that I might be able to add arguments to the handler.  You just showed me what I was looking for! thanks!

Comment: @Dexter, you're welcome.  Btw, if you can hook in at property creation time, most of the stuff you can do with `watch` can be done cross-browser (for recent browsers incl. FF4) via [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) and even if you can't, you will be able to intercept method calls via http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies which I believe is available in some of the Firefox nightlies.

Comment: I just edited to add the new code I'm using, which is somewhat working.  It seems IE and FF are both firing `Object.prototype.__defineSetter__.call(this, prop, setter);` instead of `newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val);`, so I can't get the old value yet.  I don't think I understand this prototype as well as I thought I did.  I have some reading to do.

Comment: @Dexter, please see my edits.  Probably not 100%, but the draft you put up might have problems with inherited properties and with changes in enumerability/configurability.

Comment: Ok, that's better, I had a bit of a misunderstanding about how "this" was passed to the handler, but it makes sense now.  I'm still having a problem with the old value, but by moving the `return` to it's own line, I was able to get something other than `undefined`.  It's now always returning the original value for the old value, instead of the previous value.  But I'm almost there.